# An integral with respect to the Haar measure on a unitary group

Tags: probability, statistics, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, random-matrices

Let $A,D\in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ be diagonal matrices. I need to calculate 
$$\int_{U(n)}\det{(A-HDH^\dagger)}\,\mathrm{d}H$$ 
where $dH$ is the unit invariant Haar measure on the group of unitary matrices and $H^\dagger$ is the conjugate transpose of $H$. (If $A=I$ this is very easy to solve, but I want the answer for $A\neq I$ in terms of $A$ and $D$.)

Comment: If it helps, for $n=2$ the integral evaluates to $2 \det(A-D) - \left(A_{1,1}-A_{2,2}\right)\left(D_{1,1}-D_{2,2}\right)$.

Comment: It does, thanks. Can you please let me know how you evaluate this for $n=2$?

Comment: I used _Mathematica_. Define matrix $H$: `hmat = Exp[I a/2] Table[WignerD[{1/2, m1, m2}, psi, th, phi], {m1, -1/2, 1/2}, {m2, -1/2, 1/2}];` Now define Haar measure weight `measure[psi_, th_, phi_] := Abs[Sin[th]] 1/(4 (2 Pi)^3);`. Check that it is normalized. Now evaluate `Integrate[Det[DiagonalMatrix[{a1, a2}]-hmat.DiagonalMatrix[{d1, d2}].ConjugateTranspose[hmat]] measure[psi, th, phi], {th,0,2 Pi}, {psi,0,2 Pi}, {phi,0,2 Pi}, {a, 0, 2 Pi}]`, which gives $ \det(A-D) - \frac{1}{2} \left(A_{1,1}-A_{2,2}\right)\left(D_{1,1}-D_{2,2}\right)$.

Comment: OK I see. Thanks a lot.